# How to place an expression on top of another expression using plotmath

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

If I want to generate a multi-line expression I can do:

```
over = 'OVER'
below = 'BELOW'

x_lab_title = bquote(atop(.(over), .(below)))

ggplot(data.frame()) + xlab(x_lab_title)
```

However, I would like to make `over` and `below` expressions on their own, e.g.:

```
over = expression(X^2)
below = expression(Y^2)
```

but it does not work - renders a blank space instead (why is that?). In my scenario, the real expression is much more complicated, autogenerated, and changing between subsequent plots I generate, thus I cannot simply do:

```
x_lab_title = bquote(X^2, Y^2)
```

which would work in this particular case, but not for any other value of `over` and `below`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an `expression()` in R actually acts more like a container of expressions. What you really want is the language object inside the expression object. So you could either do

```
over = expression(X^2)
below = expression(Y^2)
x_lab_title = bquote(atop(.(over[[1]]), .(below[[1]])))
```

or, even better, skip the `expression()` and just use `quote()`

```
over = quote(X^2)
below = quote(Y^2)
x_lab_title = bquote(atop(.(over), .(below)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of trial and error found a solution - this worked for me:

```
atop_string = paste0('bquote(atop(', toString(over), ',', toString(below), '))')
x_lab_title = eval(parse(text=atop_string))
```

This solution first assembles equivalent code representation and then parses it into an expression.

Even though I found a solution on my own, I am still curious why I cannot simply embed expressions in `atop`?